# python: iteration over non sequence error with linspace

Tags: python, for-loop, sequence

I have defined my own linspace command to generate a vector of elements. The iteration over this vector however fails with `iteration over non sequence of type int`

This is the linspace

```
def linspace(a, b, n=100):
    if n < 2:
        return b
    diff = (float(b) - a)/(n - 1)
    # return [diff * i + a  for i in range(n)]
    linlist = []
    for i in range(n):
        linlist.append(diff * i + a)
    return linlist
```

and this my for loop

```
n = (beginPos - endPos) / diff + 1
positions = linspace(beginPos, endPos, n)
for z in positions:
    ## Move to new position
    MoveTo(z)
```

I have no idea why the positions variable is not a valid sequence .

EDIT:
It was my definition of n the number n was negative, it needs to be calculated as

```
n = abs((beginPos - endPos) / diff) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is less than 2, `linspace` return `b`, not a list.

```
if n < 2:
    return b # <----
```

---

```
>>> def linspace(a, b, n=100):
...     if n < 2:
...         return b
...     diff = (float(b) - a)/(n - 1)
...     # return [diff * i + a  for i in range(n)]
...     linlist = []
...     for i in range(n):
...         linlist.append(diff * i + a)
...     return linlist
...
>>> linspace(1, 100, n=1)
100
>>> for z in linspace(1, 100, n=1): pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Adjust `return b` to return a list.